# Adding color to grayscale template

Tags: gimp

I have several grayscale templates (for flowers, buttons, etc.) and I want to add a color to them without losing the detail. I saw a tutorial long ago but can't remember how it was done or find the tutorial. The finished product should be a colored flower with the color matching the value of the grayscale image. Does anyone know how to do that in gimp?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Several ways:

1. Use [`Colors>Colorify`](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-colorify.html)
2. Add a new layer, fill with color, set to either `Color`, `Multiply`, or `Grain Merge` mode (each of these gives a different result).
3. Create a gradient where one is is what is your current black and the other is what is you current white (or set the background/foreground colors and the the FG/BG RGB gradient) gradient , and use Color>Map>Gradient map